# How to insert Unicode character into csv file?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a C# script in Unity that exports data to a csv file using a StreamReader. I'm trying to write the string "Δ Height" in the file for a label, but the symbol shows up as "âˆ†" when I run the script. How would I insert its Unicode character into the string so that it shows up properly in the csv file?

Comment: Is it streamReader or StreamWriter? Former is for reading while export would need write operation

Comment: @VarunK It is a StreamWriter, my mistake! Using the escape sequence \u0934 works only for the preview, not the actual excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Create the StreamReader as follows

```
new StreamReader(inputFilePath, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
```

Comment: There seems to be a side effect to this where the values put into the csv are no longer separated by commas. Instead of appearing in multiple columns, all of my data in now one column. Is there a fix for this or an alternative way to put Unicode characters in?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Encoding.UTF8. Unicode encoding won't work; Excel will show all cells in one column.

I've verified test.csv in Excel generated by following code

```
using (var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"e:\test.csv", false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            {
    sw.WriteLine("1,Δ Height,anotherValue");
}
```